# Comparing Swift arrays of named tuples

Tags: swift, tuples

I'm trying to compare two arrays of tuples. I can get what I want to work for comparing single instance of tuples, but not the array version. What am I getting wrong with the below code? Can it be accomplished in a more concise fashion?

Currently I get "Binary operator != cannot be applied to two '[(sort: Double, name: String, circleImageURLString: String?)]' operands"

```
func != <T0:Equatable, T1:Equatable, T2:Equatable> (tuple1:(sort:T0, name:T1, circleImageURLString:T2), tuple2:(sort:T0, name:T1, circleImageURLString:T2)) -> Bool {
    return tuple1.0 != tuple2.0 || tuple1.1 != tuple2.1 || tuple1.2 != tuple2.2
}

func != <T0:Equatable, T1:Equatable, T2:Equatable> (array1:[(sort:T0, name:T1, circleImageURLString:T2)], array2:[(sort:T0, name:T1, circleImageURLString:T2)]) -> Bool {

    if array1.count != array2.count {
        return true
    }

    for (index, value) in array1.enumerate() {
        if value != array2[index] {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

class myGreatTest {

    func test() {

        let array1: [(sort: Double, name: String, circleImageURLString: String?)] = [(sort:12.34, name:"Test 1", circleImageURLString:"www.test.com/1.png")]
        let array2: [(sort: Double, name: String, circleImageURLString: String?)] = [(sort:56.78, name:"Test 2", circleImageURLString:nil)]

        if array1 != array2 {
            print("Not equal")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: let me know if below answer works for you

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Apparently this is now supported natively in Swift 2.2.

Comment: Have you tested it?